# How to consume a web service using javascript with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to consume a web service by the way of a method GET, but I can't get the success function, when the program goes to the error function, the alert displays "0", I don't know why.

Here's my code using AJAX

```
function funcAddPines() {

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "url.asmx/HelloWorld",
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify({}),
  success: function (objRes) {
    alert("Entró a web-service");
  },
  error: function (e) {
    alert(e.status);
  }
});
}
```

Comment: What does your service return?

Comment: Check "Network" section of your browser dev tools. It will display details of all http requests.

Comment: can you visit your url in a browser and see results? Are you 100% sure that the right url is being called? Is this a service you created yourself?

Comment: may be you need dataType: "jsonp",

Comment: You might consider a more elaborate error function.. `error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);}`

Comment: `console.log(arguments)` would be more useful.